# The English alphabet as a vector of characters in Rust

Tags: rust

The title says it all. I want to generate the alphabet as a vector of characters. I did consider simply creating a range of 97-122 and converting it to characters, but I was hoping there would be a nicer looking way, such as Python's `string.ascii_lower`.

The resulting vector or string should have the characters a-z.

Comment: Why don't you just write `let my_ascii_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` ?

Comment: @CyrilleKa, considered that too, but is there really no better way? In my use case that alphabet could conceivably grow

Comment: Your alphabet could grow? What alphabet is this?

Comment: @JohannaLarsson What do you mean by _grow_? Can it change during execution or is it just so that you don't want do hardcode it too much?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hard-coding this sort of thing makes sense, as it can then be a compiled constant, which is great for efficiency.

```
static ASCII_LOWER: [char; 26] = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 
    'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
    'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 
    'z',
];
```

(Decide for yourself whether to use `static` or `const`.)

This is pretty much how Python does it in string.py:

```py
lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# ...
ascii_lowercase = lowercase
```

Comment: Any idea why this is not implemented somewhere as similar, simple `string.rs` in the standard library? We all know the alphabet by heart, but since we have to do this ourselves on each project, it is still possible to introduce a hard-to-detect mistake :\

Comment: @iago-lito: Rust’s standard library is broadly intended for things that *need* to be in the standard library (e.g. operator traits and primitive types), or that a very large fraction of people will use (e.g. `std::io`), or occasionally just that are extremely convenient that way (e.g. `dbg!()`). Other things belong outside the standard library, in your own code or in a crate on crates.io that people can choose to use. I have written tens of thousands of lines of Rust code, and not once needed the alphabet as a vector of chars—and I expect that I never will, either.

Comment: Got it. The right solution seems to make it part of a popular crate then :)

Answer (score 6):

Collecting the characters of a `str` doesn't seem like a bad idea...

```
let alphabet: Vec<char> = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".chars().collect();
```

Comment: Except now you now require heap allocation (the `Vec`) and it's a runtime computation instead of a compile time one.

Comment: @Shepmaster Sure, `static [char]` is probably a better approach, but he said his alphabet could grow (?), so maybe this could help...

Answer (score 6):

Old question but you can create a range of chars, so

`('a'..='z').into_iter().collect::<Vec<char>>()`